# ajax with aspx.net in visual studio 10

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i am writing a AJAX project and i wanna know the right way to do this, 
(without using bulit-in AJAX of visual studio)

i am using AJAX call with JQuery, 
here is my problem:
in th server side i created AjaxProj.aspx,
that does not contain any html code, 
in this Page_load function have all code that catch the ajax request and in the end of the code has

```
response.end();
```

i really wanna know if i am using it the right way (again i don't want to use .net AJAX from toolbox)

ty all...

Comment: are you using webmethod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please paste us some of your code to use Ajax properly you should use webmethode Functions and your function should be static like this for example :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  var text = $("#<%=ApplicationSearchResult.ClientID %>").val(); 
  // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
  $("#<%=ApplicationSearchResult.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
   source: function (request, response) {
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "Dashboard.aspx/GetTreeNodesByText",
  data: "{'text': '" + request.term + "'}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
 success: function (data) {
  response(data.d);
   }
  });
  },
  minLength: 1
  });//end auto complete

  });
```

server side function:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetTreeNodesByText(string text)
{


    List<string> Nodes = new List<string>();
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["SerialSearchDT"] != null)
    {

        DataTable DT = HttpContext.Current.Session["SerialSearchDT"] as DataTable;
        DataRow[] filteredDataTable = DT.Select("NODE_NAME LIKE '" + text + "%'");
        //  DT.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "NODE_NAME");

        for (int i = 0; i < filteredDataTable.Length; i++)
        {
            string res = filteredDataTable[i][2].ToString();

            Nodes.Add(res);

        }//end For

    }//endIF
    return Nodes.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

that's an example and i hope it can help you with your problem

Answer (score 0):

first write your server-side code:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string GetData(int userid)
{
    /*do stuff*/
    return userId.ToString();
}
```

important note: the method needs to be static and it must have the WebMethod attribute
then the javascript portion:

```
function asyncServerCall(userid) {
    jQuery.ajax({
 url: 'WebForm1.aspx/GetData',
 type: "POST",
 data: "{'userid':" + userid + "}",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (data) {
     alert(data.d);
 }

    });
}
```

then don't forget to pass the js function:

```
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="asyncServerCall(1);" />
```

and you have to enablePageMethods in the ScriptManager